# Superclass using Method of derived class C++

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have got a question regarding inheritance. My situation is this:

I have two classes (AThisWay, AThatWay) that I want to be able to swap from time to time. they both have the same method names, but do different things inside the methods. Their properties and methods get used by other classes (B). 
At the beginning I only had AThisWay and it was the superclass of B, but now I also have AThatWay and I am wondering if it is possible to make AThisWay and AThatWay a subclass ob B, so that I dont have confusion about properties or if there is a way to change the superclass of B from time to time. What is best practice in that regard?

Best
Holy

Edit:
Right now i am doing it this way (note B derives only from AThisWay), but I want B to also be able to use the method of AThatWay sometimes. Like AThisway and AThatWay are different physical models I have and I want to be able to do my calculus sometimes this way and sometimes that way just for testing my models. The fastest way I see right now is to make a copy of B and derive it from AThatWay, but that is of course not pretty and not easy to debug.

```
class AThisWay { 
public:
    int aNumber
    void aMethod() { aNumber = 1; }
}

class AThatWay {
public:
    int aNumber
    void aMethod() { aNumber = 2; }
}

class B: public AThisWay{
public:
    int anOtherNumber
    void otherMethod() 
        { 
        aMethod();
        anOtherNumber = aNumber + 2;
        }
}
```

Comment: Read up on polymorphism, virtual and overriden functions and base class pointers to a derived class.

Comment: Is the "base class pointers to a derived class" the only option, or is there a way to tell B what superclass to use when constructing it?^Is it even smart to derive A from B? Like, Class B in that case would be able to do nothing without its subclasses.

Comment: Sounds like you need *interface A*, to be used by *class B*, and implemented by those *AXxxXxx* classes. (Yes, C++ supports the concept of interface just fine even if there isn't explicit keyword for it).

Answer (score 1):

I might not get it correctly what you mean by 'swap time to time', but it seems to me that You should create a common base class of `AThisWay` and `AThatWay`, and let class `B` to use it via their common base. In this way you don't have to derive from any of those classes.

```
class AWay {
public:
    virtual void method() = 0;
}

class AThisWay : public AWay { 
public:
    virtual void method() override { /* code A */ }
}
class AThatWay : public AWay {
public:
    virtual void method() override { /* code B */ }
}
```

In class `B`:

```
 class B {
 public:
     B(bool isThat) {
         if (isThat) aWay = new AThatWay();
         else aWay = new AThisWay();
     }

     void bar() { aWay->method(); }
 private:
     AWay *aWay = nullptr;
 }
```

(the example above neglects some fine details like: deallocation of dynamic memory, it would be better to use smart pointers, etc.)

Comment: That could work, but I would like to keep the classes derived from each other since the derived class is rather an extension of my model. Does that make sense?

Comment: If you'd like to keep that structure, you can. Composition is just an another way of doing the same thing. It's hard to determine what is the best without knowing the whole situation. Here is an [article](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/multiple_inheritance.html) about the topic and its pitfalls.